# Is it necessary to encrypt the payload before sending out the post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http, request

I'm using angular as my frontend to do a login panel and send a post request to the backend which is a express API.
My domain has a SSL already, so the safety between the transfer should be good.

But I'm wondering when I open the devtool and check the request payload, the plaintext of the loginname and password is show up.

Do I need to encrypt the payload before sending post request to make it invisible?
If needed, what library I can use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you do not need to encrypt the payload. SSL will do that for you. The payload would be secure between the client and the server.

Devtools can be only opened on the local instance of chrome client. Dev Tools only starts capturing data when it is open and if a request is made. Cannot be used in man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: By any chance do you have any article that allows to deep dive into how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of TLS/SSL. You cannot perform secure encryption of payloads on a client, only on a server. Instead you rely on encoding data on the client and then on the server you check to verify the encoded data has not been changed in flight. Take a look at JWTs “json web tokens” for authflows between client and server.

Answer (score -1):

It's not mandatory but if you are dealing with fintech applications then you should encrypt your API payload, for this, you can implement RSA and AES encryption decryption Algorithms.

detail article of encryption decryption.

https://www.mdpi.com/2673-4591/20/1/14

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34718925)